# Processing continous output of program in shell script

Tags: bash

I'm developing some kind of communication between a Linux System and a printer. I'm using a Windows program with wine to do the actual communication and want to process its output in a bash script to react on the printers state change.
The windows programm continously outputs the state like this:

```
t:idle
t:idle
t:idle
t:new_job:00070035
t:51
t:51
t:30
t:30
...
t:10
t:10
t:0
t:0
t:0
t:success
t:idle
t:idle
t:idle
```

The script should trigger some action when it receives e.g. the t:0 (print finished). I tried all kinds of file descriptor redirects, but no luck.

Is it, because the Win program never exits? Can I read the output anyway?
From my understanding this should do the job:

```
while read a; do
    echo $a ... received
done < <(DISPLAY=:0.0 wine JobTracking.exe $ipPrinter 2>> $fileLog)
```

I also cannot redirect the output to a file. Like this:

```
DISPLAY=:0.0 wine JobTracking.exe $ipPrinter 2>> $fileLog 1> test.txt
```

"$fileLog" contains STDERR messages of wine, but "test.txt" is empty.

Thanks!!

Comment: If you can't redirect the output to a file, it sounds like the output is not being written to `stdout`. Try running it under `strace` to see where the output is being written to

Comment: Seems like a duplicate of https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/328951/redirect-stdout-of-a-windows-command-line-program-under-wine which has no answers

Comment: *If* the issue is that wine is writing direct to the TTY rather than to FD 1, using a program that fakes a TTY (`unbuffer wine ...`, f/e) should be all you need. Looking at `strace` or its much-lower-overhead competitor `sysdig` should make it obvious where those writes are going, and thus whether that's the case.

Comment: Maybe the output from your `echo` is getting buffered.

Comment: Thanks guys! `strace` outputs this: `write(3,...` which points to fd 3, right? But when I try `wine JobTracking.exe 192.168.139.68 >> test.txt 3>&1` there's nothing going to the file. When I use wine with programs which finish after doing output, the output goes correctly to the file. What is going on?

Comment: _when I try `wine JobTracking.exe 192.168.139.68 >> test.txt 3>&1` there's nothing going to the file_ - that's no wonder: as fd 3 describes not one of the standard pre-opened files, this file must have been opened by `wine` itself **after** it has started, so a redirection `3>&1` occuring **before** cannot be effective. You can verify which file `wine` opens with `strace -eopen` or `-efile` (as Charles Duffy hinted at).